# How can I make my Images style and be responsive?

Tags: html, css, image, responsive

for some reason the images I have been trying to put in my website refuse to style correctly. I was trying to add a border-radius and make the image reactive, but have found that no matter what the image will not style. It loads on the page, but does not have any CSS applied.

Edit: I was asked to offer the whole page, so I have editied it to have it. If anyone can look at this code and tell me how I can get my photos to round their borders and middle align without using classes, I would really appreciate it.

```css
/* Add a background color with some padding to the body */

body {
  background: #383F51;
  font-family: Geneva, sans-serif;
}

/* Header and Blog Title */

header {
  background: #91c7b1;
  margin-top: 15px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  font-family: "Electrolize", sans-serif;
}

header p {
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 24px;
}

/* navbar/*
/* top navigation bar style */
nav {
  background-color: #000;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* navigation bar links */

nav a {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-family: "Electrolize", sans-serif;
}
/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */
/* Left column */
.rightcolumn {
  flex: 1;
}

.leftcolumn {
  flex: 5;
}

/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
.row {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 12px;}

main > .row {
  display: flex;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  main > .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}

/* images (work in progress at the moment) */

/* Post layout for articles and additional areas */
.post {
  display: block;
  background-color:white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #91c7b1;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
article h2, article h2 a, .post h2 {
  font-size: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #533A71;
}

article h5{
  font-size: 16px;
  
}
.post p {
  line-height: 1.5em;
  font-size: 16px;
}
img {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 20px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

ul {
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-style: italic;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  
}
ul li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
/* Footer */

footer {
  color: black;
  margin-top: 10px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #91c7b1;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Project Incredible Indie Games</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Electrolize&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>
  <!-- Begin Header -->
  <header role="banner">
    <h1>Incredible Indie Games</h1>
    <p>Reviews and Reccomendations for the Moderate Indie Gamer</p>
    <!-- End Header -->
    <!-- Begin Navigation -->
  </header>
  <nav role="navigation">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
    <a href="about.html">About</a>
    <a href="Ori-and-The-Blind-Forest.html">Reviews</a>
    <a href="Contact-form.html">Contact</a>
  </nav>
  <!-- End Navigation -->
  <!-- End Header -->
  <!-- Begin Main Content -->
  <main role="main">
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Begin Blog Posts -->
      <section class="leftcolumn">
        <article class="post" role="article">
          <h2> <a href="Ori-and-The-Blind-Forest.html">Ori and The Blind Forest: A Soulful and Stunning Action-Platformer</a></h2>
          <h5><time datetime="2021-09-22">Sep, 22 2021</time></h5>
          <figure>
            <img src="ori-and-the-blind-forest.jpg"  alt="Ori and The Blind Forest Game Cover" aria-label="Ori and The Blind Forest Game Cover">
            <figcaption>Ori and The Blind Forest Game Cover </figcaption>
            </figure>
          <p>Ori and the Blind foret tells a story of courage, love, and sacrifice through a beautifully displayed and fluid Metroidvania style platformer. Click on this article's title to see what makes this game such an enjoyable experience!</p>
        </article>
        <article class="post">
          <h2>Ori and The Will of the Wisps</h2>
          <h5>Sep 23, 2021</h5>
          <p>This sequel to Ori and the Blind Forest both builds on the story of the previous game and expands gameplay by including new skills and weapons. Depite the improvement, this game keeps the charm of Ori and is sure to please any fan.</p>
        </article>
      </section>
      <!-- End Blog Posts -->
      <!-- Begin Sidebar -->
      <aside class="rightcolumn" role="complementary">
        <section class="post">
          <h2>About Me</h2>
          <p>Well hello there, my name is Abby Lake and I humbly welcome you to 'Project Incredible Indie Games'</p>
          <p> To learn more, please click on the 'about' tag on the upper navigation bar </p>
        </section>
        <section class="post">
          <h2>Upcoming Posts</h2>
          <ul>
            <li> Endless Ocean </li>
            <li> Endless Ocean: Blue World </li>
            <li> Rime </li>
          </ul>
        </section>
      </aside>
      <!--End Sidebar -->
    </div>
  </main>
  <!--End Main -->
  <!--Begin Footer-->
  <footer class="footer" role="contentinfo">
    <p>Blog Created by: Abby Lake</p>
  </footer>
  <!--End Footer-->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: refer to your image files with ./[filename] to avoid any confusion

Comment: Please could you make your code into a working snippet that we can run because when I tried it on my own system, with an image I'd supplied, I couldn't see any problem. the only CSS being applied (border radius) worked fine so there must be some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your other style works well, you can create a class style for the image like

```css
.img-article {
display: block;
border-radius: 20px;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
```

```html
<img class="img-article" src="ori-and-the-blind-forest.jpg"  alt="Ori and The Blind Forest Game Cover" aria-label="Ori and The Blind Forest Game Cover">
```

Comment: I was told for this assignment to limit the number of classes we use, and I had wanted to try to avoid using a class for this if possible. Would there be a good alternative?